# Enum cast to a qint32 with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, enums, casting, int

I don't understand a cast (`static_cast`) from a Qt widget example ([terminal example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-terminal-example.html)), inside the `updateSettings()` function from [settingsdialog.cpp](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-terminal-settingsdialog-cpp.html) :

```
currentSettings.baudRate = static_cast<QSerialPort::BaudRate>(
                ui->baudRateBox->itemData(ui->baudRateBox->currentIndex()).toInt());
```

Where `currentSettings` and `QSerialPort::BaudRate` are `enum`s and `currentSettings.baudRate` is a `qint32`.

What is the purpose of this cast, checking that `itemData().toInt()` belongs to `QSerialPort::BaudRate`? When i try to replace the `itemData` to an `int` which not belongs to the `enum`, no error is returned.

Comment: I don't think the post title makes any sense; what's happening here is actually the opposite -- an integer value casted to an enum type. Which is a cast you must explicitly write in the code, because integers don't automatically convert to enums.

Comment: I would way it's a but that `baudRate` is not a `QSerialPort::BaudRate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static casts do not check the validity of the cast (see [Can static_cast throw an exception in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551853/can-static-cast-throw-an-exception-in-c)).  That is why no error is returned when you try to replace the itemData to an int which doesn't correspond to the enum.

There is no purpose in casting the baudrate to an enum when it is stored as an integer.  You could remove the cast and get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt, .toInt() doesn't automatically resolve in a qint32. In some system int is not 32 bit, qint32 is guaranteed to be 32 bit.