# Which enum values are undefined behavior in C++14, and why?

Tags: c++, enums, c++14, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

**A footnote in the standard implies that any enum expression value is defined behavior; why does Clang's undefined behavior sanitizer flag out-of-range values?**

Consider the following program:

```
enum A {B = 3, C = 7};

int main() {
  A d = static_cast<A>(8);
  return d + B;
}
```

The output under [the undefined behavior sanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html) is:

```
$ clang++-5.0 -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 enum.cc && ./a.out 
enum.cc:5:10: runtime error: load of value 8, which is not a valid value for type 'A'
```

Note that the error is not on the `static_cast`, but on the addition. This is also true when an `A` is created (but not initialized) and then an `int` with value 8 is `memcpy`ied into the `A` - the ubsan error is on the addition, not the initial load.

IIUC, ubsan in newer clangs does flag an error on the `static_cast` in C++17 mode. I don't know if that mode also finds an error in the `memcpy`. In any case, this question is focused on C++14.

The reported error comports with the following parts of the standard:

[dcl.enum](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#8):

> For an enumeration whose underlying type is fixed, the values of the enumeration are the values of the underlying type. Otherwise, the values of the enumeration are the values representable by a hypothetical integer types with minimal range exponent M such that all enumerators can be represented. The width of the smallest bit-field large enough to hold all the values of the enumeration type is M. It is possible to define an enumeration that has values not defined by any of its enumerators. If the enumerator-list is empty, the values of the enumeration are as if the enumeration had a single enumerator with value 0.<sup>100</sup>

So the values of the enumeration `A` are 0 through 7, inclusive, and the "range exponent" `M` is 3. Evaluating an expression of type `A` with value 8 is undefined behavior according to [expr.pre](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.pre#4):

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined.

But there is one hiccup: that [footnote from dcl.enum](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#footnote-100) reads:

> This set of values is used to define promotion and conversion semantics for the enumeration type. ***It does not preclude an expression of enumeration type from having a value that falls outside this range.*** [emphasis mine]

Question: ***Why is an expression with value 8 and type `A` undefined behavior if "[dcl.enum] does not preclude an expression of enumeration type from having a value that falls outside this range"?***

Comment: It flags static_cast.

Comment: It doesn't preclude having a value that falls outside the range, but it doesn't require it, either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can static\_cast throw an exception in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551853/can-static-cast-throw-an-exception-in-c)

Comment: Note that the error is not on the `static_cast`, but on the addition. This is also true is an `A` is created (but not initialized) and then an `int` with value 8 is `memcpy`ied into the `A` - the ubsan error is on the addition, not the initial load.

IIUC, ubsan does flag an error on the `static_cast` in C++17 mode. I don't know if that mode also finds an error in the `memcpy`.

Comment: @jbapple: Notes are non-normative. So you cannot rely on them for well defined behavior.

Comment: @P.W: Many notes are intended to indicate how *quality* implementations *should* behave unless they document *a compelling reason to do otherwise*.  Because the Standard makes no attempt to mandate that any implementation be suitable for any particular purpose, almost all programs must rely upon implementations being of a quality appropriate to the tasks to be performed.  Except when one needs to work around the limitations of a low-quality implementation, one should be able to rely upon quality implementations behaving as described by most notes if they don't document contrary behavior.

Comment: @supercat: Thank you for the comment. Take this specific example. Clang gives a run-time error but GCC does not. I looked up the GCC manual and as far I could see they do not record any reason for not doing so. So, can we conclude that GCC is not a quality implementation? Will GCC accept a bug report on this basis? I think not.

Comment: It is hard to say; I'm not real familiar with Clang... I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and I had set my language to both c++14 and 17 and I compiled and ran your code in both x86 and x64, but instead of returning 0, I printed out the addition to the console and all trials printed 11. This doesn't seem to be an issue at all with Visual Studio. I don't know about GCC either because I haven't tried it. This could be a compiler dependent issue.

Comment: @P.W: In places where the Standard imposes no requirements but most implementations intended for a particular purpose behave in a consistent fashion, any quality implementation intended to be suitable for that purpose that behaves differently *should document a good reason for doing so*.  From what I can tell, most implementations will select for each enum an integer type which is large enough to hold all values thereof, store the enum using that type, and allow any value that fits in that type to be stored in the enum.  There are some cases where other behavior could be more useful, and...

Comment: ...there would be nothing "wrong" with an implementation behaving in some other fashion that would better serve its customers' needs provided that it documents the behavior, and provided that the alternative behavior does in fact serve its customers' needs.

Answer (score 5):

Clang flags the use of static_cast on a value that is out of range. The behavior is undefined, if the integral value is not within the range of the enumeration.

> C++ standard 5.2.9 Static cast [expr.static.cast] paragraph 7
>
> A value of integral or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to
>   an enumeration type. The value is unchanged if the original value is
>   within the range of the enumeration values (7.2). Otherwise, the
>   resulting enumeration value is unspecified / undefined (since C++17).

Comment: Note that the error is not on the `static_cast`, but on the addition. This is also true is an `A` is created (but not initialized) and then an `int` with value 8 is `memcpy`ied into the `A` - the ubsan error is on the addition, not the initial load.

IIUC, ubsan does flag an error on the `static_cast` in C++17 mode. I don't know if that mode also finds an error in the `memcpy`.

Comment: What is meant by `value is within the range of the enumeration values`? Is 3 valid for `enum{A,B,C}`? The type should hold 2^2 values, so I guess yes. What about 256 for `enum class: uint16_t{A,B,C}`? It certainly fits the underlying type, but is way out of the enumerators.

Comment: @Flamefire `3` is not valid for `enum {A, B ,C}` . 256 is valid for `enum : uint16_t{A, B, C}`. The "enumeration values" are literally the values that you define inside enums. A "value [that is] within the range of the enumerations values" is a value that is equal to one of the enumerations. See ex. [cppreference enum](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum). I think cppreference grasps it best:  `If the underlying type is not fixed and the source value is out of range, the result is unspecified (until C++17)undefined (since C++17).`

Comment: If I read that reference link correctly then `3` is valid as the range is `0..3` which `3` is inside. See also the sentence "Note that the value after such conversion may not necessarily equal any of the named enumerators defined for the enumeration. " where `7` is used as an example for `enum { A = 1, B = 2, C = 4 }`

Comment: You are right, I was wrong. The `enum{A, B, C}` has to have range of 2 bits, so `3` would be value. The key seems to be - quoting cppreference again -  `if it would fit in the smallest bit field large enough to hold all enumerators`.

Comment: I am just get confused from this comments. Does that mean that values from `0` to `15` are valid for this enum: `enum foo { a = 0, b = 10 };` since it uses `4` bits ?

Answer (score 4):

Note the phrasing of footnote 100: *"[This set of values] does not preclude [stuff]."* This is not an endorsement of the "stuff" as valid; it merely emphasizes that **this section** does not declare the stuff invalid. It is in fact a neutral statement that should bring to mind the [fallacy of the excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_the_excluded_middle). As far as this section goes, values outside the values of the enumeration are neither approved nor disapproved. This section defines which values are outside the values of the enumeration, but it is left to other sections (like `expr.pre`) to decide the validity of using such values.

You can think of this footnote as a warning to those writing compilers: do not assume! An expression of enumeration type need not have a value within the enumeration's set of values. Such a case must compile correctly unless another section classifies that case as undefined behavior.

---

For a better understanding of what exactly clang is complaining about, try the following code:

```
enum A {B = 3, C = 7};

int main() {
  // Set a variable of type A to a value outside A's set of values.
  A d = static_cast<A>(8);

  // Try to evaluate an expression of type A with this too-big value.
  if ( !static_cast<bool>(static_cast<A>(8)) )
    return 2;

  // Try again, but this time load the value from d.
  if ( !static_cast<bool>(d) ) // Sanitizer flags only this
    return 1;

  return 0;
}
```

The sanitizer does not complain about forcing a value of 8 into a variable of type `A`. It does not complain about evaluating an expression of type A that happens to have the value 8 (the first `if`). It does, though, complain when the value of 8 comes from (is *loaded* from) a variable of type `A`.

Comment: How does "Footnote 100 confirms that this is a case where going outside the range of representable values is a problem."? That footnote, to me, seems to only imply what is NOT a problem.

Comment: @jbapple "This set of values is used to define promotion and conversion semantics for the enumeration type." We are dealing with a value outside this set of values during promotion semantics. Hence a problem.

Comment: @jbapple Also, the second sentence of footnote 100 does not imply what is not a problem. I've amended my answer to cover that.

Comment: The authors of the C and C++ Standards have made no effort to fully specify all of the cases where quality implementations should all behave the same way *except when they have, and document, a compelling reason to do otherwise* [not necessarily guaranteeing anything useful about the resulting behavior].  It has become fashionable for compiler writers to limit the language to the constructs explicitly defined by the Standard, but at least for the C Standard such interpretations go directly against the authors' intention as stated in the published Rationale documents.

Comment: @supercat I'm having trouble parsing that first sentence, which might be the reason for my question: what does this have to do with my answer?

Comment: @JaMiT: Rereading what you wrote, I think I'd misunderstood it the first time.  Nevermind.

Comment: Doesn't the integral promotion happen correctly? Why undefined behavior?

Comment: @xskxzr Its not the promotion or the addition which invoke nasal demons; it is the assignation of the resulting integer to an enum.

Comment: @JaMiT I'd suggest to highlight the part of the answer actually answering, _id est_ your point about _"does not preclude"_.

Comment: @YSC I was just thinking the same thing. Besides, I've come up with a code sample that better illustrates what clang is complaining about.

Comment: Updated the example. No quotes from the spec, though, of where this might be defined as undefined behavior. Probably something to do with variables instead of expressions.

Comment: @xskxzr That's a good question, but instead of addressing it, I've modified my answer so that integral promotion is no longer mentioned.

Comment: Why doesn't the inner static_cast in `static_cast<bool>(static_cast<A>(8))` violate "If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined." The inner expression is evaluated first; it's type is `A`, and the result is not in the range of representable values for its type, right?

Comment: @jbapple It is unreliable to assume something is not undefined behavior simply because UBScan did not flag it as such. It might be not UB, or it might be a case intentionally not covered, or there might be a bug in UBScan (or possibly something else). In this case, my *guess* is that UBScan checks that a value loaded from a variable of type `A` is in the range of representable values, but does not otherwise check the evaluation of an expression of type `A`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not real familiar with Clang's compiler since I am accustomed to Visual Studio. I am currently using Visual Studio 2017. I was able to compile and run your code with language flag set to both c++14 and c++17 in both x86 and x64 debug builds. Instead of returning the addition in your example:

> ```
> return d + B;
> ```

I had decided to output them to the console:

```
std::cout << (d + B);
```

and in all 4 cases my compiler printed out a value of `11`.

*I'm not sure about GCC either as I haven't tried it with your example, but this is leading me to believe that this is a compiler dependent issue.*

I had followed your link and read section 8 in which you had referred to, but what caught my attention from that draft are the details coming from other sections namely 7 and 10.

---

**Section 7** *states:*

> For an enumeration whose underlying type is not fixed, the underlying type is an integral type that can represent all the enumerator values defined in the enumeration. If no integral type can represent all the enumerator values, the enumeration is ill-formed. It is implementation-defined which integral type is used as the underlying type except that the underlying type shall not be larger than int unless the value of an enumerator cannot fit in an int or unsigned int. If the enumerator-list is empty, the underlying type is as if the enumeration had a single enumerator with value 0.

But it is this sentence or clause that caught my attention:

> It is implementation-defined which integral type is used as the underlying type except that the underlying type shall not be larger than int unless the value of an enumerator cannot fit in an int or unsigned int.

---

**Section 10** *states:*

> The value of an enumerator or an object of an unscoped enumeration type is converted to an integer by integral promotion. [ Example:
>
> ```
> enum color { red, yellow, green=20, blue };
> color col = red;
> color* cp = &col;
> if (*cp == blue)     // ...
> ```
>
> makes color a type describing various colors, and then declares col as an object of that type, and cp as a pointer to an object of that type. The possible values of an object of type color are red, yellow, green, blue; these values can be converted to the integral values 0, 1, 20, and 21. Since enumerations are distinct types, objects of type color can be assigned only values of type color.
>
> ```
> color c = 1;        // error: type mismatch, no conversion from int to color
> int i = yellow;     // OK: yellow converted to integral value 1, integral promotion
> ```
>
> Note that this implicit enum to int conversion is not provided for a scoped enumeration:
>
> ```
> enum class Col { red, yellow, green };
> int x = Col::red;   // error: no Col to int conversion
> Col y = Col::red;
> if (y) { }          // error: no Col to bool conversion
> ```
>
> — end example ]

It is these two lines that caught my attention:

> ```
> color c = 1;        // error: type mismatch, no conversion from int to color
> int i = yellow;     // OK: yellow converted to integral value 1, integral promotion
> ```

---

So let's look back at your example:

> ```
> enum A {B = 3, C = 7};
>
> int main() {
>   A d = static_cast<A>(8);
>   return d + B;
> }
> ```

Here `A` is a complete type, `B` & `C` are the enumerators which are evaluated to a constant expression of integral type by promotion and are set to the values of `3` and `7` accordingly. This covers the declaration of `enum A{...};`

Inside of `main()` you now declare an instance or an object of `A` called `d` since `A` is a complete type. Then you assign `d` a value of `8` which is a constant expression or constant literal through the mechanism of `static_cast`. I'm not 100% sure if every compiler performs `static_cast` in the same exact manner or not; I'm not sure if this is compiler dependent.

So `d` is an object of type `A`, but since the value `8` is not in the list of enumerations, I believe this falls under the clause of `implementation defined`. This should then promote `d` to an integral type.

Then on your final statement where you return `d+B`.

Let's say that `d` was promoted to integral type with a value of `8`, then you are adding the enumerated value of `B` which is `3` to `8`, and therefore you should get an output of `11` in which I have in all 4 of my test cases on visual studio.

Now as for your compiler with Clang I can not say, but as far as I can tell this doesn't seem to produce any errors or undefined behavior at least according to Visual Studio. Then again because this code appears to be implementation defined, I think this relies heavily on your particular compiler and its version as well as the language version you are compiling it under.

I can not say that this will completely answer your question, but maybe it will shed some insight into the underlining workings of the compilers according to the documentations of the drafts & standards.

---

*-Edit-*

I decided to run this through my debugger and I put a break point on this line:

> ```
> A d = static_cast<A>(8);
> ```

Then I stepped through to execute this line of code and looked at the value in the debugger. Here in Visual Studio, `d` does have a value of `8`. However under its type it is listed as `A` and not `int`. So I do not know if this is a promoting it to `int` or not, or if it might happen to be a compiler optimization, something under the hood such as `asm` that is treating `d` as an `int` or `unsigned int`, etc.; but Visual Studio is allowing me to assign an integral value through a `static_cast` to an enumerated type. However, if I remove the `static_cast` it does fail to compile stating you can not assign a type `int` to a type `A`.

This leads me to believe that my original statement above is actually incorrect or only partially correct. The compiler is not fully "promoting" it to an integer type on assignment as `d` still remains an instance of `A` unless if it is doing so under the hood that I am unaware of.

I have not yet checked to see the `asm` of this code to see what assembly instructions are being generated by Visual Studio... therefore I am not currently able to  make a full assessment at this point. Now, later on if I have more available time; I may look into it to see what `asm` lines are being generated by my compiler to see the underlying actions the compiler is taking.

Comment: Yes, it is a compiler-dependent issue. That's why it's a question about **Clang's** undefined behavior sanitizer. If you use clang but not the sanitizer (omit the `-fsanitize=undefined` option), the sample program runs without errors. If you use clang and the sanitizer, you get the error *and* a return value of 11. (The error is not fatal.)

Comment: @JaMiT Oh okay, that makes sense now, I was kind of getting that from the question...