# Is enum E { a } e = E(2); valid?

Tags: c++, enums, language-lawyer

A recent and interesting C language-lawyer question asked:

- [Is enum { a } e = 1; valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70988698/is-enum-a-e-1-valid)

This Q&A asks the same question for the similar cases for C++<sup>(*)</sup>: are these valid?

```
enum EA { a } ea = EA(2);               // #1
enum EB { b } eb = static_cast<EB>(2);  // #2
```

<sup>I've already noted that the variation `enum EC { c } ec = EC{2};` is rejected at compile time ("cannot initialize a value of type '`E`' with an rvalue of type '`int`'), whereas `#1` and `#2` are accepted, ruling out ill-formed but not ill-formed NDR and UB for `#1` and `#2`.</sup>

---

<sup>(*) Posted here as a self-answered Q&A after being prompted to break out overly eager and misplaced C++-focused answer to the original C language-lawyer question.</sup>

Comment: Both of them are UB. Since `EA(2)` => `static_cast<EA>(2)`, they all refer to [expr.static.cast]; not with the range. This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54379993/which-enum-values-are-undefined-behavior-in-c14-and-why

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Unspecified behavior until C++14; undefined behavior since C++17

Whilst the corresponding construct is legal in C—[as answered thoroughly in the linked-to C language-lawyer Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70988698/is-enum-a-e-1-valid)—due to the stronger "compatible type" requirement, the same does not hold for C++, where "C style" unscoped enums with no fixed underlying type have subtle differences from C.

First of all, we may note that the original C example

> ```
> enum E { a } e = 1;
> ```

is not legal in C++ as C++ does not allow implicit conversion *from* an integer type *to* an unscoped enum with no explicit underlying type, thus the slightly modifyed examples of the OP

```
// Syntactically legal -> compiles.
enum EA { a } ea = EA(2);               // #1
enum EB { b } eb = static_cast<EB>(2);  // #2
```

As per [[dcl.enum]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.enum#7),

> For an enumeration whose underlying type is fixed, the values of the enumeration are the values of the underlying type. **Otherwise, the values of the enumeration are the values representable by a hypothetical integer type with minimal width M such that all enumerators can be represented.** The width of the smallest bit-field large enough to hold all the values of the enumeration type is M. [...]

the underlying type of `EA` and `EB` is implementation-defined.

As per [[expr.static.cast]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.static.cast#10):

> A value of integral or enumeration type **can be explicitly converted** to a complete enumeration type. [...] **If the enumeration type does not have a fixed underlying type, the value is unchanged if the original value is within the range of the enumeration values ([dcl.enum]), and otherwise, the behavior is undefined.** [...]

`#2` above may (depending on the implementation-defined underlying type of the `E`) lead to

- undefined behavior in C++17 and forward, via the resolution of [CWG 1766](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1766), and
- unspecified behavior in C++14 and earlier.

Conceptually, the conversion could possibly cause signed integer overflow (which is UB).

Case `#1` is, as per [[expr.type.conv]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.type.conv), also an explicit (type) conversion, and the same argument as for `#2` applies also for this functional cast case.

Comment: "the underlying type is a bit-field". No, that's never the case. Bitfields can only exist in classes, and the underlying type of an enum is not a class context. Sure, if you do have class member with that enum type, it can be a bitfield, but that's only one specific case.

Comment: @MSalters Removed that part, not really necessary, thanks.

Comment: *"hypothetical integer type"* Do you mean it can be smaller than `char`? `2` is indeed bigger than biggest value of the `enum`, but fit in a `char`. (`300` would be problematic for sure though.)

Comment: @Jarod42 Afaict, yes. ”The width of the smallest bit-field large enough to hold all the values of the enumeration type is M”. As I read it, 0 and 1 would be guaranteed to fit, whereas 2 is not (requires 2 bits). [\[dcl.enum/]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.enum#8) was explicit on this fact in C++17. It has since been rewritten (editorial change?) to the arguably more vague "hypothetical integer type".

Comment: @Jarod42 ... [P1236R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1236r1.html) (_Alternative Wording for P0907R4 Signed Integers are Two's Complement_) changed to remove the explicit bit wording ("... avoiding talking about unobservable bits as much as possible"), but afaict there is no normative change to [dcl.enum] intended in P1236R1, and the "hypothetical integer type" _could_ (/is allowed to) be a 1-bit wide integer. Indeed, [P0907R4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0907r4.html) states ...

Comment: ... "Status-quo Conversion from integral type to enumeration is unchanged: if the original value is not within the range of the enumeration values the behavior is undefined."

Comment: *"Within the range"*, so you mean for "flag" enum, you have to provide the all set bit pattern? I think you should clarify in question/answer concerned ranges (in particular your empty enum need 1-bit or 0-bit (and whereas 1 fit in 1-bit, 2 doesn't)).